# using font-size on divs without text to propagate height/other property's value to child elements

Tags: html, css

I have this [simple CSS](http://plnkr.co/edit/fUgvgHmxSIyYyM0F1OOy?p=preview):

```
div {
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}
```

The idea is that green box is positioned right below the bottom border. For that I need to explicitly specify `top` property on it. I was thinking about the ways to avoid specifying explicit measure in pixels and somehow receive it from a parent. The only solution I could come up with is to specify `font-size` on parent equal to parent's height and then reference it in the child with em. So the following solution is possible:

```
div {
  font-size: 50px; //equal to height
}

div:before {
  top: 1em;
}
```

What are the glaring drawbacks of such approach? The advantage is that greenbox div can be added to a parent with any height without needing to change `top` property of geenbox div.

Comment: specify `bottom:` instead of `top:`

Comment: @Diodeus, do you mean that I can specify negative bottom equal to greenbox div's height? Yeah, that is possible. But what about the approach in general? Have you even seen it used?

Comment: If you specify `bottom` it should be at the bottom of the parent element, regardless of its height. Maybe I don't understand what your goal is. Maybe add a diagram.

Comment: You can check out the plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fUgvgHmxSIyYyM0F1OOy?p=preview)

Comment: The one drawback of using the font size to pass a height is that if you have any text in the div, you would need to wrap the content of the div in a wrapper element and then specify a font size for the wrapper.  Mind you, it is a clever idea and in some cases, it could be just what is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest fix is to use `top: 100%` as shown below.

The 100% value computes based on the height of the parent element, so the net result is that the
top of the pseudo-element is aligned with the bottom edge of the parent block.

The advantage of this approach is that it will work for any height value of the parent `div` and any height value of the pseudo-element.

```css
div {
  height: 80px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it is really nice solution. Could you please add anything about the approach `font-size to propogate property` itself? Maybe in other situations?

Answer (score 1):

This should work. It will keep it under the parent, regardless of the parent's height.

```
div:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:-30px;
}
```